# Set encrypted home passphrase

Tags: password, encryption, home-directory

I just reinstalled Ubuntu, Natty. I set to use encrypted home, but once the system was running, I was asked to define the encrypted home passphrase. Out of haste, I skipped that, but now I want to define the passphrase but I couldn't find out how (despite how trivial this sounds).

I set my /home to a specific partition, so I may reinstall Ubuntu without losing my data whenever I need it, and I guess this is the passphare that I'd need to supply to recover my data on a new install, am I right?

Please, how can I define/change my passphrase?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that by running this command at terminal:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

The information you missed when you skiped was:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now, am I supposed to just write this down somewhere? Can't I change this passphrase to something easy to remember? Should I do that, if possible?

Comment: You can change the passphrase with this `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase` but I would advice you to keep a strong and difficult to remember passphrase. Just write it down to a secure note.